# Is “Quelle heure est-on ?” a valid way to ask about time?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, questions, pronoms-impersonnels

Is it allowed to say "Quelle heure est-on" instead of "Quelle heure est-il"? What's the difference between these questions?

Comment: Same thing.  "on" is an undefined pronoun which can replace personal pronouns, like "il" here.  I personally never heard the "on" version said by anyone around me, always the "il".  So I do not think it is grammatically a mistake, more a usage details.  http://www.espacefrancais.com/le-pronom-indefini-on-lon/#-On--se-substitue--nimporte-quel-pronom-personnel

Comment: Cela s'emploie pour l'identification du jour : On est vendredi. Je ne sais pas pour les heures.

Answer (score 4):

I thinck it's not correct, bacause it is an impersonal form (forme impersonnelle), as, for exemple "il pleut". You can't say "on pleut" (unless as a kind of joke). The "il" doesn't refer to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Quelle heure est-t-il ?***

is what is taught at school but is somewhat formal and relatively infrequent.

> ***Quelle heure il est ?***

is by far the most common way to ask "what time is it?" in spoken French.

A common but regional (Switzerland and large South-Western France) sentence is:

> ***[C'est quelle heure ?](https://www.facebook.com/francaisdenosregions/photos/a.682384071969274/697704610437220/?type=3&theater)***.

and you might even hear the colloquial and dubious:

> ***On est quelle heure ?***

perhaps groaned by someone not fully awoken in the middle of the night, and due to the proximity and confusion with:

> ***On est quel jour ?***

On the other hand, the suggested:

> ****Quelle heure est-on ?***

is extremely improbable from French native speakers if only because its formal structure doesn't mix with the informal and offbeat ***on***.

The fact is there is no real flexibility with these kind of sentences. You can't say either:

> ***<s>il est quel jour ?</s>*** or ***<s>il est quelle année ?</s>***.

I suspect the specificity of ***il est*** vs ***on est*** might be due to the fact that while we are fully and clearly "into" the space-time of the days, month and years (***on est vendredi, on est en janvier, on est en 2018, on est en hiver...***), the ephemeral hour was, until a not so distant past, an imprecise and often inaccurate concept. That means we were not really sure to be "at" a specific hour, but only aware that some device like a sundial was suggesting an hour.

We still say:

> ***il est quelle heure** à ta montre ?*

meaning that is not necessarily the right information.

Comment: I don't think it's just improbable because tones don't match, "Quelle heure est-on ?" is just not the proper interrogative form, because you don't say "On est 11h", but "Il est 11h". The same way you wouldn't say "Il est mardi" ...

Comment: @LaurentS. Not just because the tone indeed. My point was *quelle heure sommes-nous ?* seems to me more acceptable (more precisely less unacceptable) than *quelle heure est-on ?*

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR : It is ok, but why would you?

It depends of what you mean by "allowed".

Is it grammatically correct? Yes. Will that carry the meaning? Sure. But if I hear someone say that, i would assume he's either from Canada or a remote place in France.

It sounds like *"Quelle heure fait-il?"* for me: it's understandable, yet not the "classic and corect way" of saying it.

Comment: I am from Canada, and I never heard it either...

Comment: @Nic3500 Indeed, and I never said people in Canada used it ^^ Check it again: I said my **assumption** if I heard that would be that you were from those places. Niot because they use it, but because they sometimes have weird formulations that we're unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

That would be correct in my opinion. But that's really odd to the ear. I wouldn't use it myself, as a native speaker, and would be confused for a millisecond if anyone were to ask me that way.

Now if you really think about it, and had to use a more uncommon sentence construction, such as:

> Est-il tard ?

I don't think you'd be able to replace it with *"on"*. That wouldn't work, on pronunciation flow side. Or at the very least would sound odd.